# watch --color doesn't work when a pipe is involved?

Tags: linux, colors, watch

The following demonstrates that `watch` works with color, but not when a pipe is involved.

```
$ touch test.txt
$ ls | grep --color test.txt
test.txt                                  # This IS colored output

$ watch --color 'ls | grep --color test.txt'
Every 2.0s: ls | grep --color test.txt         
test.txt                                  # This is NOT colored output

$ ls | grep --color test.txt
test.txt                                  # This IS colored output

$ watch --color 'ls --color'
Every 2.0s: ls --color
test.txt                                  # This IS colored output
```

I don't understand why `watch --color` seems to work in the case of just `ls` but not when piping the output of `ls` to `grep`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Analysis

`watch` captures the output of the command it runs. Normally in an interactive shell a simple command or the last command in a pipeline prints to the terminal. In `watch` it prints to a pipe; `watch` reads from this pipe, processes and writes to its own stdout (which is usually a terminal).

`ls` and `grep` can colorize their output, each tool on its own. They support `--color=auto` option. If `auto` is used, `ls` or `grep` will colorize its output if the stdout is a terminal, but not when it's a pipe, regular file etc.

The most important thing: **`ls --color` seems to be equivalent to `ls --color=always`, while `grep --color` seems to be equivalent to `grep --color=auto`.** Investigate this:

```
unalias ls    # because `ls --color=auto' seems to be a common alias
unalias grep  # just in case

# ls prints to terminal
ls                 # no color
ls --color=never   # no color
ls --color=always  # color
ls --color=auto    # color
ls --color         # color

# ls prints to pipe
ls                | cat  # no color
ls --color=never  | cat  # no color
ls --color=always | cat  # color
ls --color=auto   | cat  # no color
ls --color        | cat  # color                      <-- compare this

# grep prints to terminal
echo foo | grep                foo  # no color
echo foo | grep --color=never  foo  # no color
echo foo | grep --color=always foo  # color
echo foo | grep --color=auto   foo  # color
echo foo | grep --color        foo  # color

# grep prints to pipe
echo foo | grep                foo | cat  # no color
echo foo | grep --color=never  foo | cat  # no color
echo foo | grep --color=always foo | cat  # color
echo foo | grep --color=auto   foo | cat  # no color
echo foo | grep --color        foo | cat  # no color  <-- to this
```

---

#### Explanation

The above difference explains your results:

- > ```
  > $ ls | grep --color test.txt
  > test.txt                                  # This IS colored output
  > ```

  Because `grep --color` behaves like `grep --color=auto` and the stdout is the terminal.
- > ```
  > $ watch --color 'ls | grep --color test.txt'
  > Every 2.0s: ls | grep --color test.txt         
  > test.txt                                  # This is NOT colored output
  > ```

  Because `grep --color` behaves like `grep --color=auto` and its stdout is not a terminal. Notes:

  - `ls` itself is colorless here.
  - **It doesn't matter a pipe is involved.** You can observe a similarly colorless result from

    ```
    watch --color 'grep --color / /etc/fstab'
    ```

    and there is no pipe in the command.
- (The third example of yours seems to duplicate the first. Skipping.)
- > ```
  > $ watch --color 'ls --color'
  > Every 2.0s: ls --color
  > test.txt                                  # This IS colored output
  > ```

  Because `ls --color` behaves like `ls --color=always`; it doesn't matter its output is not a terminal.

---

#### Solution

Invoke

```
watch --color 'ls | grep --color=always test.txt'
```

to get colors from `grep`.